# Drag&Drop prevent preview mouse up

Tags: .net, wpf, drag-and-drop, onmouseup

I want to show context menu on ListView element when Drag&Drop operation finishes by dropping some data on it. The proplem is that it seems Drag&Drop to prevent PreviewMouseUp event firing somehow. Is there some workarounds to show ContextMenu on drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely expected, the mouse events are re-routed to the drag+drop logic.  They now generate the D+D events instead.  Roughly, MouseEnter now generates DragEnter, MouseMove fires DragOver, MouseUp triggers Drop.

The logical workaround is to show the ContextMenu in your Drop event handler.